# Can I make pictures correspond with integers in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, image, bitmap

So I'm trying to make a Blackjack game and I'm trying to make pictures of the cards correspond with integers in an array.

I have an array of the deck just f.x

```
int[] deck = {1,2,3}
```

then I have pictures of the cards in a bitmap form

```
private Bitmap club3(){
return new Bitmap("Some path");
}
```

Can I associate the bitmap with a number in the array?

Comment: Yes.. you can use Generic Dictionary for that.

Comment: A class to represent a card would be better.  After all there is also a suit, rank and value to keep together.  Then a deck would be a collection of cards

Comment: Come to think of it: Blackjack has 10, Jack, Queen and King all valued at 10, so a Dictionary won't work if you index it by `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a [Dictionary][1] as Blackjack has 10, J, Q and K all valued at 10.

As Nat suggested: create a `Card`class:

```
public class Card {
  public Card(string name, int value, Suit suit, Bitmap image) {
    Name = name;
    Value = value;
    Suit = suit;
    Image = image;
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public Suit Suit { get; private set; }
  public int Value { get; private set; }
  public Bitmap Image { get; private set; }
}

public enum Suit {
  Hearts = 1,
  Spades = 2,
  Clubs = 3,
  Diamonds = 4
}
```

You can then use LINQ to query an `Enumerable` of cards (a deck basically)

Comment: Upvoted for the class approach. I'd also recommend an `enum` property to represent the card's suit, and making the setters private.

Comment: Ah the Suit's a nice addition. Making setters private is a good one for (remote) gameplay (as in: you can't alter your own `Card` class later on and submit it. Don't know enough about the rest of the author's game mechanics though.